# Javascript: How to check if URL contains a word

Tags: javascript

I want to check if the URL in a Browser contains the word "Desktop" (I startet the html file from the Desktop). Its url is: "file:///C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/TestAlert.html"

But there should appear an alert, but this doesnt works.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.contains("Desktop") > -1) {
       alert("Alert: Desktop!");
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test001</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested this in Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer.
It would be very nice, if someone can help me!

Comment: Are you looking for an `query-string` parameter or any string from the `url` ?

Comment: use indexOf instead of contains.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The method is [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("Desktop") > -1) {
       alert("Alert: Desktop!");
}
```

and you don't need DOM Ready for this.

Comment: Thank you this was realy helpful! "DOM Ready for this." that was the point

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("Desktop") > -1) {
       alert("Alert: Desktop!");
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test001</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Please try this it will give you sollution

Answer (score 2):

You can use regexp

```
url = window.location.href;
if( url.match(/desktop/gi) ) {
   alert("Alert: Desktop!");
}
```

Using this you can check two or more words as well like "/desktop|home/gi"

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf` instead

```
console.log(window.location.href.indexOf("javascript"));
```

Same rules apply, anything > -1 means it has found something

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery, you'll need to link to its source code.
Also, use `indexOf` instead of `contains`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("Desktop") > -1) {
       alert("Alert: Desktop!");
    } else {
        alert("window.location.href: " + window.location.href);
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test001</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Tip: When you have Javascript problems, hit f12 in your browser to open the development tools and then f5 to refresh the page. Then check your console tab for error messages, e.g. 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined', and your sources tab for any parts of your code that are underlined in red.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location.href;
            console.log(url);
            console.log(~url.indexOf("#product-consulation"));
            if (~url.indexOf("#product-consulation")) {
                console.log('YES');
                // $('html, body').animate({
                //     scrollTop: $('#header').offset().top - 80
                // }, 1000);
            } else {
                console.log('NOPE');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> if(window.location.href.indexOf("YOUR DESIRED WORD PUT HERE") > -1) {
> alert("The word is there!"); }

Works exactly you want!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).