# WPML |Get the current ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE with JS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, wpml

I tried to retrieve the current ICL language with this code but it doesn't work.

```
var getLangCode = '<?php echo ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE; ?>';

alert(getLangCode);
```

Do you know how can I get the current language code with javascript ?

Thanks in advance !

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to place the quotes in the right places.

Remove quotes before `<?php` and after `?>` and surround the PHP constant with double quotes.

```
var getLangCode = <?php echo '"' . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE . '"' ; ?> ;

alert(getLangCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution did not work for me. Actually, **none** of the solutions I've found which involved `<?php` or `echo` worked for me.

The workaround that worked for me was checking if the URL of the page contains the language code. Example for Spanish:

```
<script>
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/es/") > -1) {
   alert("Spanish language");
}
</script>
```

You [don't need DOM Ready for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34649157/1198404), just place it on your header. Simple, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is:

```html
   var lang = document.documentElement.lang;
```